# How to prevent clearing of form fields in form is invalid using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How to prevent clearing of form fields like **userid** (if it is already exits) when form gets submit.

my code

```
<form method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 lab" for="id_username">Username *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input  name="username" id='id_username' class='form-control' placeholder='Username' minlength="5" maxlength="15" type='text' required></div>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 lab" for="id_email">E-Mail *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10" >
                    <input class='form-control' name="email" id='id_email' placeholder='user@mydomain.com' pattern="(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.com$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.org$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.co\.in$)" maxlength="200" type='email' required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 lab">Password *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" name="password1" id="id_password1" placeholder="Password" minlength="8" maxlength="15" type="password" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 lab2">Password Confirmation *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" name="password2" id="id_password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" minlength="8" maxlength="15" type="password" required>
                </div>
            </div>
       <input type="submit"/>
         </form>
```

This is my code which backed is django

Comment: On click of submit button, form gets submitted hence page is unloaded. If values are invalid, use `e.preventDefault()` in `submit` handler..

Comment: can explain it with code

Comment: When you submit the form the page will be refreshed and the way to keep some info is to store them somewhere else example using the cookies or the locaStorage options

Comment: yes Rayon is correct try e.preventDefault()

Comment: @RahulMohite can add code to matchup your question...;)

Comment: basically i using django

Comment: wait @jai i will post the code

Comment: okay your problem is in front end

Comment: It can be both a front and a back end issue. If validation is being done on the front end, then you should prevent form submission at the first place like what others have described, using `event.preventDefault()`. If you are performing validation on the backend instead, simply echo the value of the user input back into the input elements `value` attribute.

Comment: when i submit the form it goes to backend and check the form and the aging render to forntend with errors

Comment: you can use `event.preventDefault()` or `return` both won't clear form fields if its invalid

Comment: how to use event.preventDefault() can give the code

Comment: wait @stone i m trying

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can try as;

```
window.onload=function(){
 $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //now ajax call to do what ever you want with form data
  })
}
```

And if you really don't want to use ajax then ,

```
window.onload=function(){

 $("#idfield").val(localStorage.getData('id'));

 $("form").submit(function(e){
    localStorage.setData("id",$("#idfield").val());
  })
}
```

Comment: Not working means, this code refreshes your page after clicking on submit button?

Comment: but my fields shouldn't get cleared it is clearing my form fileds

Comment: Ok , you must keep the code inside window.onload function, as I updated my answer

Comment: exactly where @koushik

Comment: window.onload=function(){
 $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //now ajax call to do what ever you want with form data
  })
}

Comment: Have you written the ajax  where I mentioned; //now ajax call to do what ever you want with form data

Comment: i have try your method but my submit button is not working now

Comment: what is that id="idfield"

Comment: idfield is the field in the form where you want to retain the value. It is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the form is invalid then it calls **preventDefault()**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e){
    // validation code here
    if(!valid) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: by using this my submit button gets stuck not clicking

Comment: can u give me the link

Comment: Try Yourself in Bootstrap Try It Editor of w3 schools website

Comment: Did U miss any script files

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly, you should under stand what is possible a possible flow submitting form through JQuery.
1. It is obvious that you understand the you are writing code once DOM is ready with following code.

```
jQuery("document").ready(function(){
});
```

2. Give id to your form to grab through jquery. Then use .submit() function of JQuery https://api.jquery.com/submit/
   here is as example from one of my code:

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function(){
    
    jQuery( "#form-id" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();       
    
    jQuery.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: your_server_side_execution_url,
            data: jQuery(this).serializeArray() 
        }).done(function( data ) {                        
            var rtn = JSON.parse(data);                                    
        });                
    });
    
});
```

If you still not able to run the code. Put JS/JQuery in question as well to figure out your issue.